# Google cloud storage Interoperability with S3 interface failed with SignatureDoesnotmatch

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Basically, i try to test GET call to access the bucket ACL by HTTPS url using Developer Keys from S3 browser. Here is the url: 
https://mybucket1.storage.googleapis.com/?acl

But I am getting following error:

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. 
Check your Google secret key and signing method. TaskID: 108
```

I just following the simple migration process from S3 to GCS found [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#migration-simple) but I am still facing issues. Can any one of you explain why the above steps are not working with S3 browser? The above link says it will work. To make it work, should I change any HTTP/custom headers here?

Below is my GET call

```
GET /?acl HTTP/1.1

 Host: mybucket1.storage.googleapis.com

 User-Agent: curl/7.55.1

 Accept: */*

 Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 
Credential=GOOGCMZOMXVFOS2EJ4PUP7YR/20190531/us-east1/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=5e3c9d4df679b0ea847ff2216842d34ea43c1366e67d6d36b338e59b3c515f73

 x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855

 x-amz-date: 20190531T042146Z
```

Comment: That error message should be immediately followed by a `<StringToSign>` section that includes the full content of what was signed by the server to verify your signature. Please take a look at it and make sure there's nothing surprising there.

Comment: Hi Lakshmikantha, as asked by Brandon, is there a <StringToSign> value in the error response? It will help us debug your issue.

Comment: ErrMsg:

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA25620190531T092930Z20190531/us-east1/s3/aws4_request401997af89a550b9cf7b215edb141f72a15bcc3707dbc13f49088690de958618</StringToSign><CanonicalRequest>GET/mybucket1/acl=host:storage.googleapis.comx-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOADx-amz-date:20190531T092930Zhost;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-dateUNSIGNED-PAYLOAD</CanonicalRequest></Error>

Comment: Sorry for late response.

Comment: The same GET request works, if I use X-GOOG*  headers in Authorization Header.

Answer (score 0):

In your call you still using the AWS keys, you need to replace your Authorization header according this doc [Authenticating in a simple migration scenario](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#authentication)

Comment: Hi,
Can you please point out where it has gone wrong.
As per doc, I don't need to change the security headers of AWS, only generate the cryptography key using Google Secret key, that I did.

"https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#authentication
In a simple migration scenario, you only change the header to use your Google Developer access key and make sure the Signature you attached is calculated with your Google Developer secret key.

In a simple migration, you don't need to change credential scope if you are using AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.

Comment: can you check if your key is correct?, I had the same issue when I used intentionally a wrong key

Comment: Hi,The keys are correct. When I changed the Headers to use X-GOOG*. It worked. The same GET request worked for following Authorization header.

Authorization: GOOG4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=GOOGCMZOMXVFOS2EJ4PUP7YR/20190604/us-east1/s3/goog4_request,SignedHeaders=host;x-goog-content-sha256;x-goog-date,Signature=0ce135221e7d15f906e7fe37ce113a21e1c5bb3e8e6cd58d150c486dac94c5ab

Comment: I think that you mustn't put your crypto keys in here because is a public site, you need to change intermediately in order to avoid any security issue @Lakshmikantha Reddy

Comment: I had corrupted them before pasting here.